# C - Why does my string return Null when sending it to a function?

Tags: c, string, function, null

I am a total beginner, but I am doing a project for school and I just can't seem to get it working.

The goal is simple: scan 5 strings, count their vowels and then sort it alphabetically using functions.

I have the vowel part sorted out, but when I send the already scanned strings to my function, it gets read as null so I can't sort it there.

I'll show you the code very simplified so I can highlight the problem more easily (without the bubble sort):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char abc(char nombres[])
{
    printf("\n%s", nombres[3]);
}
int main()
{
    char nombres[20][20];
    printf("Ingrese 5 nombres:\n")

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        scanf(" %s", nombres[i]);
    }
    
    abc(nombres);

    return 0;
}
```

In my imagination, it should display the third input that was scanned, but the output reads:

```
Ingrese 5 nombres
juan
alberto
lautaro
milo
beatriz

(Null)
```

Hopefully, you have already spotted the problem, if so, please help me correct my code.
I can send the rest if you want, I just trimmed it for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: The code you have posted has errors in it. You are passing a 2D array to a function that accepts a 1D array, and are also printing a character `nombres[3]` using `%s` instead of `%c`. I think you'll have to post the rest of your code too since this code isn't enough to reproduce the problem you describe.

Comment: Aside: `char abc(char nombres[]) { printf("\n%s", nombres[3]); }` is defined to return a `char`, yet returns nothing.  Maybe instead of returning  `char`, use `void`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're passing to the function isn't compatible with the parameter type.

The function expects a parameter of type `char []`, which as a function parameter is exactly the same as `char *`.  What you're passing to it is a `char [20][20]`.  Your compiler should have warned you about this.  It should also have warned you about sending `nombres[3]` inside of `abc` which has type `char`, i.e. a single `char` and not a string like the `%s` format specifier expects.

You need to change the parameter type to the function to match what you're passing to it and how you're using it.

```
char abc(char nombres[20][20])
```